# md-datepicker md-min-date not work when is a binding

Tags: datepicker

Sorry for my english. I have md-date-picker related to each other. When I reduce the date in the first, the second change 3 month plus of the first, and the sencond md-min-date change with the first model. See the codepen to better understanding.

http://codepen.io/patapron/pen/MJEmyY?editors=1010

My problem:

When I change the first date less than 3 months, I get an error in the minimum date of the second

I tried to change the min date binding for a funcion like this:

```
<form name="myOtherForm" flex layout="row" layout-align="center center">  
    <md-input-container>
      <label>From</label>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDateFrom" 
                     name="dateFieldFrom" 
                     ng-change="plusTo()"
                     md-max-date="myDateTo">
      </md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>           
    <md-input-container>
      <label>to</label>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDateTo" 
                     name="dateFieldTo" 
                     md-min-date="minDateTo()">
      </md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
  </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `$timeout` to your `$scope.plusTo` function, so our modification takes place after *md-datepicker*. :

```
$scope.plusTo = function() {
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.myDateTo = moment($scope.myDateFrom).add(3, 'months').toDate();
  });
};
```

and do not forget to inject `$timeout` into your controller:

```
... .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
      ...
    }
```

you can also use `$scope.$applyAsync` instead of `$timeout` (you have `$scope` injected already), but I personally prefer '$timeout'

Comment: Thank you very much @Andriy, I really have spent hours trying to fix it without getting any results. [codepen](http://codepen.io/patapron/pen/MJEmyY?editors=1010)

The problem is solved, but, do you really know why this may be happening? Bye.